# Add 3D object to Android Studio and render into EasyAR camera view

Tags: java, android, android-studio, augmented-reality, easyar

I have an app build in Android Studio, using EasyAR for the Image Marker functionally.

Right now the camera recognize a target from my server and draws a cube on top of the image. Using this function:

```
public void render(Matrix44F projectionMatrix, Matrix44F cameraview, Vec2F size)
{
    float size0 = size.data[0];
    float size1 = size.data[1];

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_coord_box);
    float height = size0 / 1000;
    float cube_vertices[][] = {
        /* +z */{size0 / 2, size1 / 2, height / 2}, {size0 / 2, -size1 / 2, height / 2}, {-size0 / 2, -size1 / 2, height / 2}, {-size0 / 2, size1 / 2, height / 2},
        /* -z */{size0 / 2, size1 / 2, 0}, {size0 / 2, -size1 / 2, 0}, {-size0 / 2, -size1 / 2, 0}, {-size0 / 2, size1 / 2, 0}};
    FloatBuffer cube_vertices_buffer = FloatBuffer.wrap(flatten(cube_vertices));
    GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cube_vertices_buffer.limit() * 4, cube_vertices_buffer, GLES20.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
    GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GLES20.glUseProgram(program_box);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_coord_box);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos_coord_box);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(pos_coord_box, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_color_box);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos_color_box);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(pos_color_box, 4, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, true, 0, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(pos_trans_box, 1, false, cameraview.data, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(pos_proj_box, 1, false, projectionMatrix.data, 0);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_faces_box);
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 4, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, i * 4 * 2);
    }

    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_coord_box);
    float cube_vertices_2[][] = {
        /* +z */{size0 / 4, size1 / 4, size0 / 4},{size0 / 4, -size1 / 4, size0 / 4},{-size0 / 4, -size1 / 4, size0 / 4},{-size0 / 4, size1 / 4, size0 / 4},
        /* -z */{size0 / 4, size1 / 4, 0},{size0 / 4, -size1 / 4, 0},{-size0 / 4, -size1 / 4, 0},{-size0 / 4, size1 / 4, 0}};
    FloatBuffer cube_vertices_2_buffer = FloatBuffer.wrap(flatten(cube_vertices_2));
    GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cube_vertices_2_buffer.limit() * 4, cube_vertices_2_buffer, GLES20.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos_coord_box);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(pos_coord_box, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_color_box_2);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos_color_box);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(pos_color_box, 4, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, true, 0, 0);
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 4, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, i * 4 * 2);
    }
}
```

But I have a 3D Model I would like to show instead of the box.

I just can't figure out what the best practise is for importing 3d objects to Android Studio and how to render them into the EasyAR camera view.